# Sorting tuples that reference objects

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of tuples. Each tuple represents a grid x and y value. I want to sort the tuples based upon the grid's object attribute that they represent.

**For example:**

my grid of `y * x elements` where each element has an object named node. Each node has an attribute called globalGoal.

```
list a = [(1, 2), (2, 4)]

(1, 2) reference grid[1][2]

grid[1][2] = node

node.globalGoal = (int) value is the value I wish to sort

if (1, 2) represents the globalGoal value of 75 and
   (2, 4) represents the globalGoal value of 45 then
I want my list ordered as
[(2, 4), (1, 2)]
```

my test code that I assembled from other stackoverflow answers is:

```
class getSortedKey:
  global grid

  def __init__(self, node):
    self.node = grid[node[0]][node[1]].globalGoal

  def __cmp__(self, othernode):
    return(cmp(self.node, othernode))

a = [(1, 2), (2, 4)]
a.sort(key=lambda b: getSortedKey(b))
```

firstly I have a problem getting my grid list containing all the nodes into the class, secondly I get the error:

TypeError: `'<'` not supported between instances of `'getSortedKey' and 'getSortedKey'`

Am I going in the right direction, or is there a simple way to achieve this.

I can achieve what I want by writing my own sorting function (bubble sort) but it is too slow. My next step would be to write a quick sort but I'm struggling with sorting in my particular scenario, so I thought using Pythons own sort would be far better, but obviously I have hit a wall.

Any help gratefully received. I have searched for similar answers but nothing seems to be what I need (unless I have mis understood other answers)

Comment: You would have saved a lot of time (and learned a lot more) properly reading the `list.sort()` documentation and/or this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: I did, there's a lot to take in. Obviously I mis understand somethings that may appear obvious to you. They don't to me, hence why I came here.

Comment: I wasn't born with some innate ability to code in Python you know - I learned by reading the doc and trying things in the interactive shell to confirm my understanding ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I going in the right direction, or is there a simple way to achieve this.

There's indeed a much simpler way...

```
a.sort(key=lambda c: grid[c[0]][c[1]].globalGoal)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it returned None. I print(a) which gives [(3, 2), (4, 3)] then did your code and print(a) again returns None. Clearly there is something I am not grasping here.

Comment: OK, I have found my problem - thankyou - this does work I was tryiing to do a = a.sort() which obviously failed.

Comment: @AndyP `list.sort()` does indeed return `None` - like all builtin methods that modify their content in place FWIW.

Comment: Glad to have been of some help - and please feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: I did click on the up arrow but it said I don't have enough reputation? Unless I accept it in a different way? I have also ticked the green arrow, which is probably what you wanted :)